# Potential memory leak in Python Flask app when reading feather files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flask, heroku, memory-leaks

I have created a small terminology query webapp using Flask and deployed it on Heroku (served with Gunicorn). The app reads feather files (pre-generated using a script that converts a set of csv and xlsx files, some of them having 100,000+ rows) into pandas and searches for terms input by the user (using POST). The feather files are about 70MB total. Each time an API call is made, it reads the data and returns the corresponding results. However, each reading of the files increases memory usage, and it won't go down after completing the call. Each subsequent reading thus continues to increase memory usage, and eventually, the Heroku server crashes.

I have read many threads on StackOverflow about the same issue, but I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

Steps I've taken:

- using --preload and setting web concurrency to 2 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974081)
- using gc.collect() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740832/need-help-identifying-a-memory-leak-involving-matplotlib-and-flask) (it helps free some memory but there is no drastic change)
- reading the feather files once before any API call is made → this directly causes a memory quota exceeded error in Heroku

Here's what my Flask app looks like:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pandas as pd
import gc
#import memory_profiler as mp

app = Flask(__name__)

#@mp.profile
def load_dataframes(target_lang):
        df_gl = pd.read_feather(f"data/feather/glossary_{target_lang}.ft")
        df_exc = pd.read_feather(f"data/feather/merged_exc_{target_lang}.ft")
        return df_gl, df_exc

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
#@mp.profile
def main():
    term = request.json["term"]
    target_lang = request.json["target_lang"]
    exact_match_gl = request.json["exact_match_gl"]
    exact_match_exc = request.json["exact_match_exc"]

    try:
        print(f"Query: {term}. Target lang: {target_lang}")
        df_gl, df_exc = load_dataframes(target_lang)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

    if exact_match_gl == 1:
        print(f"Searching for '{term}' in glossary… Exact match: true")
        results_gl = df_gl[df_gl["term_en-US"] == term]
    else:
        print(f"Searching for '{term}' in glossary… Exact match: false")
        results_gl = df_gl[df_gl["term_en-US"].str.contains(term, case=False, na=False)]
    
    if exact_match_exc == 1:
        results_exc = df_exc[df_exc["Source Term"] == term]
        print(f"Searching for '{term}' in translations excerpts… Exact match: true")
    else:
        results_exc = df_exc[df_exc["Source Term"].str.contains(term, case=False, na=False)]
        print(f"Searching for '{term}' in translations excerpts… Exact match: false")

    if len(results_gl) > 0:
        gl_source = results_gl["term_en-US"].tolist()
        gl_translation = results_gl["term_" + target_lang].tolist()
        gl_source_pos = results_gl["pos_en-US"].str.split(n=1).str[1].str.lower().tolist()
        gl_target_pos = results_gl["pos_" + target_lang].str.split(n=1).str[1].str.lower().tolist()
        gl_source_def = [s[:1].lower() + s[1:] for s in results_gl["def_en-US"].str.split(n=1).str[1].tolist()]
    else:
        gl_source, gl_translation, gl_source_pos, gl_target_pos, gl_source_def = [''] * 5

    if len(results_exc) > 0:
        exc_source = results_exc["Source Term"].tolist()
        exc_translation = results_exc["Translation"].tolist()
        exc_cat = results_exc["String Category"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
        exc_platform = results_exc["Platform"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
        exc_product = results_exc["Product"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
        exc_version = results_exc["Version"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
    else:
        exc_source, exc_translation, exc_cat, exc_platform, exc_product, exc_version = [''] * 6
    
    del [[df_gl, df_exc]]
    gc.collect()
    df_gl = None
    df_exc = None
    
    # JSON Response
    response = {"gl_source": gl_source, "gl_translation": gl_translation, "gl_source_pos": gl_source_pos, "gl_target_pos": gl_target_pos, "gl_source_def": gl_source_def,
    "exc_source": exc_source, "exc_translation": exc_translation, "exc_cat": exc_cat, "exc_platform": exc_platform, "exc_product": exc_product, "exc_version": exc_version}
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Using [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), the increase in memory usage can be clearly seen when reading the df. This is an extract of a log when starting the app and making a first search:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    17     81.0 MiB     81.0 MiB           1   @app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
    18                                         @mp.profile
    19                                         def main():
    20     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       term = request.json["term"]
    21     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       target_lang = request.json["target_lang"]
    22     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       exact_match_gl = request.json["exact_match_gl"]
    23     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       exact_match_exc = request.json["exact_match_exc"]
    24
    25     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       try:
    26     81.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           print(f"Query: {term}. Target lang: {target_lang}")
    27    362.2 MiB    281.2 MiB           1           df_gl, df_exc = load_dataframes(target_lang)
    28                                             except Exception as e:
    29                                                 print(e)
    30                                                 raise
```

That would be fine if that much memory was used every request, as it does not exceed Heroku's 512MB quota. But when making a second search:

```
Query: test. Target lang: fr-FR
Filename: C:\Users\spide\Documents\termic-main\search.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     1                                         from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
     2                                         import pandas as pd
     3                                         import memory_profiler as mp
     4                                         import gc
     5
     6                                         app = Flask(__name__)
     7    366.9 MiB    366.9 MiB           1
     8                                         @mp.profile
     9    384.8 MiB     17.9 MiB           1   def load_dataframes(target_lang):
    10    533.4 MiB    148.6 MiB           1           df_gl = pd.read_feather(f"data/feather/glossary_{target_lang}.ft")
    11    533.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           df_exc = pd.read_feather(f"data/feather/merged_exc_{target_lang}.ft")
    12                                                 return df_gl, df_exc
```

And it goes on and on after each search, never decreasing.

Using gc.collect() helps a bit but it's quite insignificant:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67    329.4 MiB    -29.4 MiB           1       gc.collect()
```

Something I have trouble understanding is that, in my memory-profiler logs, I find that memory is sometimes freed spontaneously. I guess that's the garbage collector doing its work normally (as then gc.collect() does nothing), but what is strange to me is how the memory usage can still be so high:

```
    35                                             if len(results_gl) > 0:
    36   1098.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           gl_source = results_gl["term_en-US"].tolist()
    37   1098.7 MiB      0.2 MiB           1           gl_translation = results_gl["term_" + target_lang].tolist()
    38                                                 gl_source_pos = results_gl["pos_en-US"].str.split(n=1).str[1].str.lower().tolist()
    39   1098.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           gl_target_pos = results_gl["pos_" + target_lang].str.split(n=1).str[1].str.lower().tolist()
    40                                                 gl_source_def = [s[:1].lower() + s[1:] for s in results_gl["def_en-US"].str.split(n=1).str[1].tolist()]
    41                                             else:
    42                                                 gl_source, gl_translation, gl_source_pos, gl_target_pos, gl_source_def = [''] * 5
    43    631.3 MiB   -467.4 MiB           1
    44    631.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if len(results_exc) > 0:
    45                                                 exc_source = results_exc["Source Term"].tolist()
    46    631.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           exc_translation = results_exc["Translation"].tolist()
    47    631.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           exc_cat = results_exc["String Category"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
    48    631.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           exc_platform = results_exc["Platform"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
    49    631.4 MiB      0.1 MiB           1           exc_product = results_exc["Product"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
    50    631.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           exc_version = results_exc["Version"].fillna("unknown").tolist()
    51    456.4 MiB   -175.0 MiB         221       else:
    52                                                 exc_source, exc_translation, exc_cat, exc_platform, exc_product, exc_version = [''] * 6
    53
    54                                             del [[df_gl, df_exc]]
    55    456.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
```

When it comes to Heroku, using log-runtime-metrics shows that there is a significant increase in memory swap:

```
2023-05-03T12:06:33.052510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.305321644.814f8ad6-3350-4d6d-934c-25f61f3013de sample#memory_total=92.37MB sample#memory_rss=77.64MB sample#memory_cache=14.73MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=25972pages sample#memory_pgpgout=2325pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB

(…)

2023-05-03T12:21:44.199217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.305321644.814f8ad6-3350-4d6d-934c-25f61f3013de sample#memory_total=100.52MB sample#memory_rss=85.84MB sample#memory_cache=14.68MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=28070pages sample#memory_pgpgout=2336pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2023-05-03T12:21:55.402309+00:00 app[web.1]: Query: test. Target lang: fr-FR
2023-05-03T12:22:05.926772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.305321644.814f8ad6-3350-4d6d-934c-25f61f3013de sample#memory_total=426.72MB sample#memory_rss=413.42MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=13.30MB sample#memory_pgpgin=145870pages sample#memory_pgpgout=40033pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB

(…)

2023-05-03T12:23:02.203757+00:00 app[web.1]: Query: exactly. Target lang: fr-FR
2023-05-03T12:23:17.312190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.305321644.814f8ad6-3350-4d6d-934c-25f61f3013de sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2023-05-03T12:23:17.361744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.305321644.814f8ad6-3350-4d6d-934c-25f61f3013de sample#memory_total=695.81MB sample#memory_rss=511.64MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=184.16MB sample#memory_pgpgin=207192pages sample#memory_pgpgout=90008pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2023-05-03T12:23:17.383034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=695M(135.9%)
2023-05-03T12:23:17.388969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Could you please tell me if it really is a memory leak issue? What additional steps could be taken to fix it? Any help would be very much appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: Some ideas: use `usecols` on the dataframe, so you just get the data you need; change the data type of the retrieved columns, cache results; if memory is really a problem try Dask.